# Using variables from another script int Unity 5

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, scripting

I need to use some variables defined in a script but when I call them their values are 0. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Example:

Script1.cs

```
public int cont;


public void Method() { cont++; }

void Update() { Method(); }
```

Script2.cs

```
public Script1 usingScript1;

void MethodX()
{
    usingScript1.GetComponent<Script1>();
    Debug.Log(usingScript1.cont);
}

void Update() { MethodX(); }
```

This script should be showing the "cont" variable increasing since it's being called from Update(), but that's not happening. When I call it, it's 0 and don't increase.

Also, I refer the object which contains Script1.cs in the Ispector.  It must be a simple thing that I'm missing. I even tried calling Method().

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a zillion-times duplicate. Interestingly it's the single most common question about Unity from new hobbyists trying Unity.

Comment: _"DO NOT USE EVER Update...experts never need to use it"_ - Incorrect. _"[Update is the most commonly used function to implement any kind of game behaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)"_

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow , are you talking about avoiding `Update` when `RigidBodies` are involved? In that case I agree with you.  Otherwise there is nothing wrong with overriding `Update` as you can see in my spiffy _[GPGPU n-Body galaxy simulation](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/n-body-galaxy-simulation-using-compute-shaders-on-gpgpu-via-unity-3d/)_. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to what everyone mentioned, have you tried initializing "cont" ?

This

```
public int cont;
```

becomes

```
public int cont = 0;
```

Also try initializing it in the Start() function if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The function called Method() is never called anywhere in this code. Since it's the only thing that modifies the value of the variable called cont, if it is never called, cont will never change from its default value of zero.</strike>

EDIT: Whoops!
Okay, the actual problem here is that you need to change

```
usingScript1.GetComponent<Script1>();
```

to

```
usingScript1 = GetComponent<Script1>();
```

The latter line of code sets the variable usingScript1 so that you can use it in your code. The former simply calls a function without doing anything with the information it returns.

EDIT: GetComponent() will only work is the two scripts are attatched to the same gameobject. Otherwise, you can use FindObjectOfType().

Comment: just because it's not the way that you would do it doesn't mean it's wrong... you don't gotta go downvoting my answers...

Comment: Hi Halp!  I do not downvote.  Your script is wrong ... you're thinking of something like Find("that game object").GetComponent<> ...

Comment: If the two scripts are on the same gameobject, GetComponent() will work just fine. I do realize that I should have informed Sean of this in case he was not already aware. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it and never thought about it. As simple as it. Instad of creating an object, I just made the variables static and call  'em using the class.

Script1.cs

```
public static cont;
```

Script2.cs

```
Script1.cont;
```

And it works.

Comment: As a rule do not do this in Unity